# Bootstrap-ui and mobile menu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The problem I have is that when on a small device/screen mobile menu (3 lines) simply does nothing on click. No errors either. I've tried many variations of solutions I've seen but cannot get anything to work - Determined not to fall back into JQ

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="NavBarCtrl">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="isCollapsed = false" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="/images/logo/logo.png" href="/caption-it/" class="logo img-responsive"> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Bring your photos to life</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#captionIt"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/caption-it/facebook-photos"><i class="fa fa-facebook whiteText"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Facebook </span>Photos</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> My Captionise <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#uploadPhotos">Upload Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#myUploadedPhotos">My Uploads</a></li>
          <li><a href="#myCaptionised">My Captionised Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="/caption-it/browser-button">Browser Button</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="logOut(); return false"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var capApp = angular.module('capApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngCookies']);

function NavBarCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = true;
}
```

I've tried with and without using the bootstra.js but no difference.

Only just (a week) started with Angular.

Really struggling with this, an ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working solution of my current work.

take a look at

```
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse" ng-class="{'collapse':!isCollapsed}">
```

and

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-init="isCollapsed = false">
```

No need to specify in controller. Choice is yours where you initialize.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-init="isCollapsed = false">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="getactivemenu('')" ui-sref="home">Site Name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse" ng-class="{'collapse':!isCollapsed}">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li  ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ><a ui-sref="enquiries">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li  ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ><a ui-sref="enquiries">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li  ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ><a ui-sref="enquiries">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li  ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ><a ui-sref="enquiries">Menu 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect - only issue is if i click to expand the menu, then click site name, which is a link back to homepage, the page loads but the menu doesn't close

Comment: Sorry by mistake i deleted that.                                                                                      <a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="getactivemenu('');isCollapsed='false'" ui-sref="home">Site Name</a>                                                                                        
 is the simple trick.

Comment: No I tried that but it fails, instead I added `ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"` - I presume getactivemenu(''); is one of your functions to get active controller or something?

Comment: yep.sorry. I didnt delete that. Set it to false always. As if you are working with desktop version, i am not sure, but could hide your nav menu items. I didnt try it out.